# how to vary the firing angle control in matlab to obtain the various modes of operation of hvdc transmission system

Tags: matlab

I am doing project in HVDC.i had constructed the rectifier and inverter station to transfer the power via HVDC.IN matlab demo hvdc station is found. i want to know how to vary the firing angle of the rectifier and inverter station to obtain the various modes of operation of hvdc station such as when the voltage in ac side is decreased and ac voltage when further reduced...i wnt to obtain the various modes of operation of HVDC station

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer to this on the electronics stack exchange - 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107460/average-output-voltage-of-a-fully-controlled-full-wave-rectifier

If you're up to wading through the theory behind this, I recommend starting to read further into the control of the firing pulses - for example this [PDF on bidirectional HVDC](http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/d.jovcic/pages/Pap436.pdf) gives a good overview. It's very dependant on the topology (how the converter is configured), however